# extension closing after entering prompt input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I've created a chrome extension where it asks for a prompt to rename something, but for some reason it closes the whole extension after submitting the prompt. It still works, just the extension closes every time a prompt is submitted.

The thing is, for some reason, this doesn't happen to everyone. I tested it on a windows computer and the extension stays open, but on my macbook where I code it, it closes the extension.

I can't find any reason this is happening or any other questions similar to this, any help would be appreciated!

code:

```js
var notename = prompt("Enter name:")
var regPattern = /^[\w\-\s]+$/;
var testthing = regPattern.test(notename)
if (testthing==true && notename.length > 0){
    chrome.storage.local.set({["note-"+notenumber+"-title"]: notename}, function(){
    })
}else{
    alert("Invalid name! Only alphanumeric characters allowed.")
}
```

Comment: Can we have some code pasted here? that will be useful to understand the problem better.

Comment: alright, its literally just `var name = prompt("name: ")`

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome. Don't use `prompt`. Use an `input` element.

Comment: @wOxxOm oh alright will do so thanks